# Javascript How to Build Option Tag With Custom Increments

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm still new to Javascript and I need to know how to build the option tag. I want to keep the first option tag custom and the rest with increments of 15 from 0 - 1000. This is the current code I'm using but the problem is that the value is being set to the increment number and I don't want to keep typing each array value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var teamArray = ["(Custom Number Example) 120", "0", "15", "30", "45"];
        var arLen=teamArray.length;
        for(var i=0; i<arLen; i++){
            document.getElementById("minutes").options[i]=new Option(teamArray[i], i);
        }
    }

    window.onload=myFunction;
</script>

<select id="minutes">
</select>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the current implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript does not have a `range` function built in, unfortunately, but you can create this array with a simple `for` loop.

```
var teamArray = ["(Custom Number Example) 120"];
for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i += 15) {
    teamArray.push(i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/Ne8XD/

Comment: thanks, the only issue is the value now. if you look at the value it is being set to the increment number rather than the the one inside the tag.

Comment: I think that might work thanks :)  Can you give me a sample with the value set just incase

Comment: @webdev what do you mean by the value set?

Comment: i mean the hidden value thats part of the tag, this -> <option value>, does it matter if it's set, still new to html?

Comment: @webdev if you want the content and value to be the same, `value` can be omitted.  Otherwise set `teamArray[i]` as the first *two* arguments to `new Option`